# text file convert to dictionary (why my loop doesn't work)

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, text

This is the original text file and I want to extract only 'reviewTexts' part.
[My Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gCUU.png)

I try to make it convert to a dictionary and then extract the key' reviewTexts' and the following is the code that I tried to clean the text file before change it to a dictionary:

```
f = open('baby.txt','r')
lines=f.read().split("\n")[:30]
str_list = list(filter(None, lines))
str_list
```

And the result like this:

```
 ['reviewerID:A1HK2FQW6KXQB2',
 'asin:097293751X',
 'reviewerName:Amanda Johnsen "Amanda E. Johnsen"',
 'helpful:[0, 0]',
 "reviewText:Perfect for new parents. We were able to keep track of baby's feeding, sleep and diaper change schedule for the first two and a half months of her life. Made life easier when the doctor would ask questions about habits because we had it all right there!",
 'overall:5.0',
 'summary:Awesine',
 'unixReviewTime:1373932800',
 'reviewTime:07 16, 2013',
 'reviewerID:A19K65VY14D13R',
 'asin:097293751X',
 'reviewerName:angela',
 'helpful:[0, 0]',
 'reviewText:This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]',
 'overall:5.0',
 'summary:Should be required for all new parents!',
 'unixReviewTime:1372464000',
 'reviewTime:06 29, 2013',
 'reviewerID:A2LL1TGG90977E',
 'asin:097293751X',
 'reviewerName:Carter',
 'helpful:[0, 0]',
 "reviewText:Helps me know exactly how my babies day has gone with my mother in law watching him while I go to work.  It also has a section for her to write notes and let me know anything she may need.  I couldn't be happier with this book.",
 'overall:5.0',
 'summary:Grandmother watching baby',
 'unixReviewTime:1395187200',
 'reviewTime:03 19, 2014']
```

The result looks fine but when I use this code in a loop some strange things happened. The result cannot show the overall lines but the last 10 lines.

```
dict_temp ={}
f = open('baby.txt','r')
lines=f.read().split("\n")[:30]
str_list = list(filter(None, lines))
str_list
for one in str_list: 
    k = one.split(':')[0]
    v = one.split(':')[1]
    dict_temp[k] = v

print(dict_temp)
```

```
{'reviewerID': 'A2LL1TGG90977E', 'asin': '097293751X', 'reviewerName': 'Carter', 'helpful': '[0, 0]', 'reviewText': "Helps me know exactly how my babies day has gone with my mother in law watching him while I go to work.  It also has a section for her to write notes and let me know anything she may need.  I couldn't be happier with this book.", 'overall': '5.0', 'summary': 'Grandmother watching baby', 'unixReviewTime': '1395187200', 'reviewTime': '03 19, 2014'}
```

Please help me figure out the reason and any other way to solve this question ( extract only 'reviewTexts' part)

Comment: Can u edit ur question with the text present in ur text file instead of attaching a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your loop is that there are multiple instances of the same key in your text file. As your loop goes through the list and finds a new key (say 'reviewText'), it stores the value associated with it in the dictionary. But when the loop encounters the string 'reviewText' again, which it will as there are multiple reviews in your file and each review contains all of the keys, the value for that key is overwritten. You lose your old value for the key and the new value is stored in place of it.

If you just want to extract the 'reviewText' for each review, you can use the list comprehension as suggested in another answer. It assumes that there's just one ":" in the string and the text 'reviewText' can't be found the value (looking at them as key-value pairs) for any of the strings. Following is a safer version of the same idea.

```
reviews = [r[10:] for r in strlist if r[:10] == 'reviewText']
```

Rubber duck debugging is very effective for problems like this as it'll be obvious what the problem is once you go through each iteration of the loop tracking what every line does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `list comprehension` instead of creating a `dictionary`:

```
lst = ['reviewerID:A1HK2FQW6KXQB2',
 'asin:097293751X',
 'reviewerName:Amanda Johnsen "Amanda E. Johnsen"',
 'helpful:[0, 0]',
 "reviewText:Perfect for new parents. We were able to keep track of baby's feeding, sleep and diaper change schedule for the first two and a half months of her life. Made life easier when the doctor would ask questions about habits because we had it all right there!",
 'overall:5.0',
 'summary:Awesine',
 'unixReviewTime:1373932800',
 'reviewTime:07 16, 2013',
 'reviewerID:A19K65VY14D13R',
 'asin:097293751X',
 'reviewerName:angela',
 'helpful:[0, 0]',
 'reviewText:This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]',
 'overall:5.0',
 'summary:Should be required for all new parents!',
 'unixReviewTime:1372464000',
 'reviewTime:06 29, 2013',
 'reviewerID:A2LL1TGG90977E',
 'asin:097293751X',
 'reviewerName:Carter',
 'helpful:[0, 0]',
 "reviewText:Helps me know exactly how my babies day has gone with my mother in law watching him while I go to work.  It also has a section for her to write notes and let me know anything she may need.  I couldn't be happier with this book.",
 'overall:5.0',
 'summary:Grandmother watching baby',
 'unixReviewTime:1395187200',
 'reviewTime:03 19, 2014']

[print(elem.split(':')[-1]) for elem in lst if 'reviewText:' in elem]
```

Output:

```
Perfect for new parents. We were able to keep track of baby's feeding, sleep and diaper change schedule for the first two and a half months of her life. Made life easier when the doctor would ask questions about habits because we had it all right there!
This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]
Helps me know exactly how my babies day has gone with my mother in law watching him while I go to work.  It also has a section for her to write notes and let me know anything she may need.  I couldn't be happier with this book.
```